# MonoTouch doesn't build a sample project

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

This is very weird. I just got MonoDevelop (2.4.1) along with MonoTouch (3.2.2, evaluation version) to my Mac running Mac OS X 10.5.8 and tried to build a solution with it. All I got after hitting "Run" button is

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs /noconfig "/out:/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/TestProject.exe" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" "/r:/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" /nologo /warn:4 /debug:+ /debug:full /optimize- /codepage:utf8 "/define:DEBUG"  /t:exe "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/Main.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/MainWindow.xib.designer.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/MainViewController.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/MainView.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/MainView.xib.designer.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/FlipsideViewController.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/FlipsideView.cs" "/Users/antonzuravskij/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/FlipsideView.xib.designer.cs" -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 

dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs: line 2: 81676 Trace/BPT trap          MONO_PATH=/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1 /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mono /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/smcs.exe "$@"


dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/smcs: line 2: 81676 Trace/BPT trap
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MonoTouch 3.2.2 requires Xcode 3.2.5 with iOS SDK 4.2 final, which requires OSX 10.6

Comment: There isn't much point in that, since apple will only accept applications built with Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2 final

Comment: I know, and I'm looking into upgrade, but for today it's easier to get MonoTouch of a previous version. BTW which version shall run with XCode 3.1?